# Disabling items in the list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a requirement wherein I want to disable items in the list view. 
Say **e.g., I have 5 items in the listview out of which I want to only enable 1 item.**

Note: disabling means greying out the item.

Following is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, movies);
```

I don't want to go with the custom adapter wherein we get the `getView()`.

Is there any other way to implement this functionality?

Comment: As per ur requirement u have to make custom adapter.I think no other choice.

Comment: not possible without custom Adapter..

Comment: If you extend the ArrayAdapter instead of BaseAdapter (or the ListAdapter interface) you'll only have to implement the isEnabled method, because getView and the other required methods would be implemented by the parent (ArrayAdapter)

Answer (score 1):

In the adapter there is a method name **isEnabled** which you can **override**. **This is called for each row like getview.** The **onclicklistener** will only fire if this function returns true. So try doing that in **your custom adapter**.

```
@Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if(YOUR CONDTITION){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Without adapter:

Then you need to disable the item by getting view at specific position.

Comment: Yeah, but anuja wrote that he/she doesn't want to implement custom Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Please implement the listener for this method  `setOnItemSelectedListener` . So you can disable any item that you want.

Comment: I don't want to disable any item, on item click. When the list view is created, it should have 4 items disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable item using:

```
final Set<Integer> disabledPositions = new HashSet<Integer>();
disabledPositions.add(positionYouWantToDisable);
disabledPositions.add(positionYouWantToDisable);
disabledPositions.add(positionYouWantToDisable);

ListView listView = new ListView(this);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg3) {
      if(!disabledPositions.contains(position) {
         // do what you want
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this.. But unfortunately it is not working

Comment: the getChildAt() is returning me null

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    final List<Integer> disabledItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    disabledItems.add(0);
    disabledItems.add(2);
    lvMovies.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            if (disabledItems.contains(arg2)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DISABLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                arg1.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOT DISABLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                arg1.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
```